# Build Bootstrap theme for distribution

Tags: webpack, sass, bootstrap-4, theming

My goal is to make a reusable Bootstrap theme for several company projects. I've followed the [official theming docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/) and created my `custom.scss`. **But how do I build the theme for distribution?** As far as I understand the end result should be a compiled an minified css file like `my-theme.min.css`

First I've tried Webpack's SASS and CSS loaders but then realized that Webpack's purpose is to create a JavaScript bundle and not a CSS file.

Then I've read about the official [build tools](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/) which seem to be doing everything that I want but I don't understand how to reference an npm script from `node_modules` and make my `custom.scss` the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

So you have done all the work and all you need now is convert the `scss` to `css` file. Let's try this step by step.

1. Install **node** if not already installed. https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Install **node-sass** globally by typing this in terminal: `npm install node-sass -g`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
3. Convert scss to css by typing in terminal `node-sass style.scss style.css` where your **style.scss** is the file you have created and **style.css** is the file that you want to generate. Follow the command-line mode for more options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#command-line-interface

You would further want minify the generated css file. You can do this by following the shared link in the 3rd point: `node-sass style.scss style.css --output-style compressed`.